# system-function call asynchron?

Tags: c, windows, system, sleep, wine

At one place in a code i call an external tool with the [system-Call](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/). I work with Wine and program with C.

The call is like this:

```
system("blabla.exe outfile");
```

The command is dynamically generated to change the outfile. A few lines later i try to open the generated file with `fopen`, but `fopen` returns `NULL`.

If i change the call to the following everything works:

```
system("blabla.exe outfile");
Sleep(2000);
```

But i don't like to wait 2 seconds... And this solution is very bad.
I think the `system`-Call works synchron? So the sub-process an all its (File-)Handles should be closed after the `system`-Call, not? I'm a bit confused about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` call is synchronous, according to the man page it returns after the execution ends. I suspect there's something with wine flushing file handles.